# Why is iframe with youtube src not working in bootstrap site?

Tags: iframe

I am having issues with the code as well. In all browsers the iframe cannot content be displayed.

I am using the following code:

```
    <!--Grid row-->
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

  <!--Grid column-->
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <p class="h5 mb-4">Making Sense of Complexity</p>


     <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-3">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6wjC0sxD2o" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Grid column-->

</div>
<!--Grid row-->
```

A quick google search shows that something is disabling the iframe.
Any ideas?

This is what shows up/how it is rendered:
[page cannot be found]

Comment: The same thing happens with the iframe embed code from youtube.

Comment: How can I use this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options  I tried making a Web.config.txt file (or does it need to be an xml file?  I tried that too and it didn't fix it though.  I added the following content to my Web.config.txt file and put it in the same root as my index.html file that has the above code:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>

<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

    </system.web>
</configuration>